# Pass MVC user(owin cookie) to WebApi(bearer token) cross domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies, asp.net-web-api, bearer-token

I know there are a lot of similar questions, but I haven't been able to find anything specific to this scenario.

I have an MVC5 app, using OWIN cookie authentication (no asp.net identity stuff), and now I'm adding a new Web Api project(using .net5/MVC6, and bearer tokens). This Web Api application will be on a different domain and server, but the only thing calling it will be my MVC application. I'm trying to figure out how to pass along the logged in user from the MVC app to the Web Api app. Is there a way to generate the bearer token from the cookie or something?

I know I can probably create the token endpoint on the Web Api that takes the username and password, then checks it against the database, then issues a token. And maybe that's still the correct way to do this. I'm just wondering if there's a more accepted method since the user is already logged in to the MVC app.

Thanks!

Comment: Who generates the auth token in the first place? Your app, external auth server? What protocol is used?

Comment: @MvdD The token for the web api project? I've used that OAuth Authorization Server thing in the past, but it doesn't look like that is being brought over for .net 5. I've used an example I found on SO that used JWT. And yeah, either way the web api application generates it, no sso server or anything.